# NextAuth - Secondth time signing in with the same google account, OAuthAccountNotLinked error

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, next.js, next-auth

I am building a web-app with `react`, `nextjs`, `typescript`, `mongoose`, `mongodb` and as authentication, I'm using `next-auth`.

A couple of points you have to know to make sure to solve the right problem.

1. You have two options to log in, one of them is via credentials (email/password) and the other option is via Google Sign in
2. What currently is working is when you created an account via credentials with example@gmail.com, and the user tries to sign in with a Google account with example@gmail.com, the user should get an error. (that's working)

But, what currently is happening is:

When a user signs up for the first time with a Google account (the email isn't registered in the db), it all works perfectly. When the user tries to sign in with the SAME google account, `next-auth` gives me a `"OAuthAccountNotLinked"` error. (url to be exact: `http://localhost:3000/auth/error?error=OAuthAccountNotLinked`)

Below, can you find all relevant code in order to possibly help me:

[...nextAuth].ts

```ts
import NextAuth, { Account, Profile, Session, User } from "next-auth";
import GoogleProvider from "next-auth/providers/google";
import { MongoDBAdapter } from "@auth/mongodb-adapter";
import clientPromise from "@/lib/mongodb";
import { Adapter } from "next-auth/adapters";
import EmailProvider from "next-auth/providers/email";
import CredentialsProvider from "next-auth/providers/credentials";
import connectDb from "@/utils/connectDB";
import bcrypt from "bcryptjs";
import UserModal from "@/models/User";
import { JWT } from "next-auth/jwt";

export default NextAuth({
  adapter: MongoDBAdapter(clientPromise) as Adapter,
  providers: [
    CredentialsProvider({
      name: "Credentials",
      credentials: {
        email: {
          label: "Name",
          type: "text",
          placeholder: "example@domain.com",
        },
        password: { label: "Password", type: "password" },
      },
      async authorize(credentials) {
        await connectDb();

        const user = await UserModal.findOne({ email: credentials?.email });
        console.log(user);
        if (!user) {
          throw new Error("Email is not registered.");
        }

        const isPasswordCorrect = await bcrypt.compare(
          credentials!.password,
          user.password
        );
        if (!isPasswordCorrect) {
          throw new Error("Password is incorrect.");
        }
        return user;
      },
    }),
    EmailProvider({
      server: process.env.EMAIL_SERVER,
      from: process.env.EMAIL_FROM,
      // maxAge: 24 * 60 * 60, // How long email links are valid for (default 24h)
    }),
    GoogleProvider({
      clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_ID as string,
      clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_SECRET as string,
    }),
  ],
  pages: {
    signIn: "/signin",
    error: "/auth/error",
  },
  session: { strategy: "jwt" },
  secret: process.env.NEXTAUTH_SECRET,
  callbacks: {
    async signIn({ user, account }: { user: User; account: Account | null }) {
      if (account?.provider === "google") {
        await connectDb();
        const existingUser = await UserModal.findOne({ email: user.email });

        if (!existingUser) {
          const newUser = new UserModal({
            name: user.name,
            email: user.email,
            image: user.image,
            password: bcrypt.hashSync(user.id),
            emailVerified: true, 
            role: "user", 
            credits: 1, 
          });

          try {
            await newUser.save();
          } catch (err) {
            console.log(err);
            return false; // returning false will not log the user in
          }
        }
      }
      return true; // if the above checks pass, continue the login process
    },
    async jwt({ token, account }) {
      try {
        await connectDb();
        const user = await UserModal.findOne({ email: token.email });
        if (user) {
          token.provider = account?.provider;
          token.credits = user.credits;
        }
      } catch (error: any) {
        console.log(error);
      }

      return token;
    },
    async session({ session, token }) {
      return { ...session, user: { ...session.user, credits: token.credits } };
    },
  },
});`
```

Signin page

```
import Particels from "@/components/particles";
import Spinner from "@/components/spinner";
import { Button } from "@/components/ui/button";
import Input from "@/components/ui/input";
import { AuthErrorType, errorMessages } from "@/utils/authErrorMessages";
import { zodResolver } from "@hookform/resolvers/zod";
import { NextPageContext } from "next";
import { getCsrfToken, signIn } from "next-auth/react";
import { Inter } from "next/font/google";
import Image from "next/image";
import Link from "next/link";
import { useRouter } from "next/router";
import { useState } from "react";
import { SubmitHandler, useForm } from "react-hook-form";
import toast from "react-hot-toast";
import { FcGoogle } from "react-icons/fc";
import { FiLock, FiMail } from "react-icons/fi";
import z from "zod";

const inter = Inter({ subsets: ["latin"] });

const FormSchema = z.object({
  email: z.string().email("Please enter a valid email adress."),
  password: z
    .string()
    .nonempty("Please enter a password.")
    .min(6, "Password must be atleast 6 characters.")
    .max(52, "Password must be less than 52 characters."),
});

type FormSchemaType = z.infer<typeof FormSchema>;

export default function Login({
  callbackUrl,
  csrfToken,
}: {
  callbackUrl: string;
  csrfToken: string;
}) {
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const {
    register,
    handleSubmit,
    formState: { errors, isSubmitting },
  } = useForm<FormSchemaType>({
    resolver: zodResolver(FormSchema),
  });
  const onSubmit: SubmitHandler<FormSchemaType> = async (values) => {
    setLoading(true);
    try {
      const res = await signIn("credentials", {
        redirect: false,
        email: values.email,
        password: values.password,
        callbackUrl,
      });
      if (res?.error) {
        return toast.error(res.error);
      } else {
        return router.push("/");
      }
    } catch (error: any) {
      throw new Error(error);
    } finally {
      setLoading(false);
    }
  };

  const router = useRouter();

  return (
    <div className="flex h-screen w-full flex-col items-center justify-center p-4">
      <Image
        alt="backgroundremoverpro logo"
        width={244}
        height={28}
        src="/backgroundremover_pro-logo.svg"
        className="mx-auto absolute top-16 cursor-pointer"
        onClick={() => router.push("/")}
      />
      <h1 className="text-2xl font-semibold">Sign In</h1>
      <p className="text-base text-gray-400 mt-2">
        Enter your email and password below to sign in.
      </p>
      <div className="md:w-[360px] text-center">
        <form
          method="post"
          action="/api/auth/signin/email"
          onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}
          className="mt-8"
        >
          <input type="hidden" name="csrfToken" defaultValue={csrfToken} />
          <Input
            name="email"
            type="text"
            icon={<FiMail />}
            placeholder="example@emaple.com"
            register={register}
            error={errors?.email?.message}
            disabled={isSubmitting}
          />
          <div className="flex flex-col text-right">
            <Input
              name="password"
              type="password"
              icon={<FiLock />}
              placeholder="***********"
              register={register}
              error={errors?.password?.message}
              disabled={isSubmitting}
            />
            <Link
              href="/forgot-password"
              className="text-sm text-white/50 hover:text-white transition mt-2"
            >
              Forgot Password
            </Link>
          </div>
          <Button type="submit" variant={"primary"} className="w-full mt-6">
            {loading ? (
              <>
                <Spinner />
                Logging in...
              </>
            ) : (
              "Login"
            )}
          </Button>
        </form>
        <Button
          onClick={() => signIn("google")}
          variant={"secondary"}
          className="w-full mt-3"
        >
          <FcGoogle className="inline-block mr-2" />
          Sign in with Google
        </Button>

        <Button
          variant={"link"}
          className="w-full mt-4"
          onClick={() => router.push("/signup")}
        >
          Create an account
        </Button>
      </div>
      <Image
        alt="light-fade"
        className="absolute z-20 top-0 right-0 opacity-75 pointer-events-none   "
        src="/test.png"
        height={800}
        width={1200}
      />
      <Particels />
    </div>
  );
}

export async function getServerSideProps(ctx: NextPageContext) {
  const { req, query } = ctx;
  const callbackUrl = query.callbackUrl
    ? query.callbackUrl
    : process.env.NEXTAUTH_URL;

  if (
    query?.error &&
    typeof query.error === "string" &&
    Object.keys(errorMessages).includes(query.error)
  ) {
    return {
      redirect: {
        permanent: false,
        destination: `/auth/error?error=${query.error}`,
      },
      props: {
        errorMessage: errorMessages[query.error as AuthErrorType],
      },
    };
  }

  const csrfToken = await getCsrfToken({ req });
  return {
    props: {
      callbackUrl,
      csrfToken,
    },
  };
}
```

From the sign in, the serverside props the errorMessages/AuthErrorType

```
export type AuthErrorType =
  | "OAuthSignin"
  | "OAuthCallback"
  | "OAuthCreateAccount"
  | "EmailCreateAccount"
  | "Callback"
  | "OAuthAccountNotLinked"
  | "EmailSignin"
  | "CredentialsSignin"
  | "SessionRequired"
  | "Default"
  | "Configuration"
  | "AccessDenied"
  | "Verification";

type ErrorMessage = {
  [key in AuthErrorType]: string;
};

// use the error messages as you like, but it is usually a good idea to not show exactly what went wrong due to security reasons
export const errorMessages: ErrorMessage = {
  OAuthSignin: "Error in signin in with Google",
  OAuthCallback: "Error in signin in with Google",
  OAuthCreateAccount: "Could not create user",
  EmailCreateAccount: "Could not create user with provided email",
  Callback: "Error in the OAuth callback handler route",
  OAuthAccountNotLinked:
    "The email on the account is already exists, try signin in with the same method used while signing up",
  EmailSignin: "Sending the e-mail with the verification token failed",
  CredentialsSignin: "wrong credentials",
  SessionRequired: "Session error",
  Default: "Failed to authenticate, something went wrong, contact owner",
  Configuration:
    "There is a problem with the server configuration. Check if your options are correct",
  AccessDenied: "Signin Error, Something went wrong",
  Verification: "Signin Error, Something went wrong",
};
```

Hopefully some one can help me out with this one.

If you have any questions, please let me know so I can provide all info you needed in order to solve this :D

Googling, asked other developers, chatgpt, nothing worked.

Also, good to mention, I rechecked all env codes, and they are all perfect.

Comment: Do you find a solution? I am having same issue.

Comment: No, I have decided to jump to Supabase since nobody wants/able to solve this simple issue.

Answer (score 1):

in my case the problem was with the Accounts and Sessions in the database. There were many overlapping sessions and accounts data for the same associated acount and was throwing the same error as yours. I cleared the sessions and then accounts data which were not needed(in development, were created due to so many test login attempts during dev) and the problem was solved.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I've also faced the same issue and eventually found where the problem was.

If you are using `GoogleAuth` or some other `OAuth` providers, and it is giving you the `OAuthAccountNotLinked` error when you login the second time with the **same** `OAuth` provider, it is likely because you are adding extra field to the User's account but returned the wrong `id` in the `profile()` callback or simply because the `Adapter` might be buggy.

### Possible issue 1: `porfile()` callback return wrong id

For instance, I'm using the 'profile()' callback to add extra field to the users account from `GoogleAuth`, the id return in the callback is actually for the `providerId` in the `Account` table instead of the id being used for creating `User`

```js
  GoogleProvider({
    clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
    clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
    /**
     * @param {import("next-auth/providers/google").GoogleProfile} profile
     * @returns
     */
    profile(profile) {
      return {
        id: uuid(), // <== this is where my problem is, 
                    // this field is actually for the `providerAccountId` in the 
                    // `Account` table, so it should use `profile.sub` instead.
        name: profile.name,
        email: profile.email,
        image: profile.picture,
        emailHash: md5(profile.email.toLocaleUpperCase()),
        emailVerified: profile.email_verified,
      };
    },
  }),
```

### Possible issue 2: buggy `Adapter`

And if you are not trying to use the `profile()` callback but still facing the issue, it is mostly the `Adapter` is buggy and you will have to write your own `createUser` and `linkAccount` logic like this (or just move to other database):

```js
NextAuth({
  adapter: {
// I never use this adapter before, 
// but if you are pretty sure that you have done nothing wrong, 
// then it is likely this adapter is broken and you will be 
// better off to move to other nosql database, or you will 
// have to write your own logic for creating new account and new user.
    ...MongoDBAdapter(clientPromise), 
    async createUser(data) {
      // create user logic goes here
    },
    async linkAccount(data){
      // create account logic goes here
    }
  },
});
```